# Check that $df_x(v) = (v,v).$

Tags: calculus, differential-topology

Here is a proof that I am totally different from my classmates'. So I am requesting for expert reference here. Thank you. :-)

> Let $f: X \rightarrow X \times X$ be the mapping $f(x) = (x,x).$ Check that $df_x(v) = (v,v).$

$\begin{eqnarray*}
df_x(v) &=& \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t}\\
& = & \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(x+tv, x+tv) - (x,x)}{t}\\
& = & \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(tv,tv)}{t}\\
& = & \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (v,v)\\
& = & (v,v).
\end{eqnarray*}$

Comment: Isn't $X$ supposed to be an arbitrary manifold?

Comment: Yes, @DanielFischer - so I can't do it in this way, since how I did it implies in $\mathbb{R}^n$ space?

Comment: Not exactly $\mathbb{R}^n$, but close enough, $x + tv$ isn't defined for general manifolds.

Comment: May I ask why $x + tv$ implies closed manifold?

Comment: I didn't say "closed". I meant $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a close enough approximation. $x + tv$ is okay for small enough $\lvert t\rvert$ if $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - or any finite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Oh thanks, then I didn't see the answer works around this issue..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace $x + tv$ by a curve through $x$, $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma '(0)=v$, you would get the standard proof of the result.

In an arbitrary manifold $X$, that is the only way to make sense of the expression $x+tv$.